# Insert new Fragment next in already running Android ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Trying to dynamically add Fragments to different pages in an Android ViewPager.

Dynamically adding a Fragment to the end of the list of Fragments works fine, but attempting to add to the next slot (the unseen page after the current viewable page).  I've tried adding to the arraylist of fragments and using notifyDataSetChanged and trying to use set on each of the fragments after to set each to the previous item.

Edit:  updated code

```
class MainPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public MainPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public PageFragment getItem(int position) {
        return PageFragment.newInstance(Datamart.getInstance().getURLs().get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return Datamart.getInstance().getURLs().size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        PageFragment pageFragment = (PageFragment) object;
        for ( int i = 0; i < getCount(); i++ ) {
            if ( pageFragment.getURL().equals( Datamart.getInstance().getURLs().get(i) ) ) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
}
```

Within the Datamart:

```
public class Datamart {

    static Datamart instance;

    private ArrayList<String> URLs;
    private MainPagerAdapter mainPagerAdapter;
    private ViewPager viewPager;

    public Datamart() {
        URLs = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public static Datamart getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = new Datamart();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    public MainPagerAdapter getMainPagerAdapter() {
        return mainPagerAdapter;
    }

    public void setMainPagerAdapter(MainPagerAdapter mainPagerAdapter) {
        this.mainPagerAdapter = mainPagerAdapter;
    }

    public ViewPager getViewPager() {
        return viewPager;
    }

    public void setViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        this.viewPager = viewPager;
    }

    public void addToEnd( String URL ) {
        URLs.add(URL);
        mainPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public void addNext( String URL ) {
        URLs.add(viewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1, URL);
        mainPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getURLs() {
        return URLs;
    }

    public void setURLs(ArrayList<String> URLs) {
        this.URLs = URLs;
    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect there's an error in your add() method. Can you show the code for that?

Comment: It seems to me the problem is in mainPagerAdapter, assuming the subclass for PagerAdapter. Looking at the logcat, I suspect issue is in instantiateItem(). Maybe post some/most of the code in that class.

Comment: Added the code to help better explain-

Comment: Since you included more code, I rewrote my answer to give a blow-by-blow description of what happened and how to fix it.  Check it out.

Comment: The guide was fantastic, although I think I've missed something resulting in one more bug.  The code for adding a new page works fine, but nothing loads on it, it just stays as an empty page and sometimes after lots of page switching will display the same webview as the pages around it.

Answer (score 2):

`ViewPager` is doing its darndest to try and keep track of where all the fragments go, and you got it confused because you inserted a fragment in the middle without telling it.

Let's do an example.  Say that you have two pages so that you are displaying the first page and the second page is the offscreen page to the right.  You have `fragment0` for the first page and `fragment1` for the second page.

First, keep in mind that since `ViewPager` is managing the offscreen pages to the immediate left and right, *it already thinks it knows what the second page fragment is*, which is `fragment1`.

When you insert a fragment between those existing page fragments, `ViewPager` is not going to ask you right away which fragment is at the second position, it's going to ask you *if the fragment at the second position has changed.*

This is where `getItemPosition()` comes in.  You didn't implement `getItemPosition()` in your `FragmentPagerAdapter`, so the default behavior of `getItemPosition()` is to return `POSITION_UNCHANGED`.  (As you'll see, this is why adding a fragment at the end doesn't cause an error.)

So when you called `notifyDataSetChanged()`, the `ViewPager` called `getCount()` and saw that instead of two pages, you now have three.  It then called `getItemPosition()` for page 0 and page 1 (the pages it knew about) and your default implementation told it that nothing had changed.

But something *did* change, you inserted a page/fragment in the middle of the two existing pages.  `ViewPager` asked you if the second page changed, and your `getItemPosition()` should have returned `2` instead of `POSITION_UNCHANGED`.

Now because your `getCount()` returned `3` instead of `2`, `ViewPager` knows that there is a new page at the end that it doesn't know about, so it calls `getItem()` to get the new fragment.

Here is where the error occurs.  Your `getItem()` method returned `fragment1` for page 3, and `ViewPager` choked because *you handed it the fragment that it already knew about*. Specifically, it uses the fragment's tag for some housekeeping.  It creates a tag out the the page's container id and the item position (page number).  So at any given time it expects that either (a) the tag is null, or (b) the tag will be the same value that it already calculated from the container id and the item position.  Neither of those conditions were true, so that's why `IllegalStateException` was thrown.

So how do you fix this?

You implement a `getItemPosition()` that does the right thing.  When your `getItemPosition()` is called, you scan through your list of fragments, and when you find a matching fragment, you return the index of the fragment.  If you removed a fragment such that there's no matching fragment in your list, you return `POSITION_NONE` to tell the `ViewPager` that the page should be removed.  `ViewPager` will then call your `getItem()` method to get the new page.  In this way, `ViewPager` can always stay in sync with your adapter.

---

When I write a `FragmentPagerAdapter`, I don't even use the fragments in the model.  If I were writing your adapter, I would just have a list of URLs, since it looks like each page/fragment has it's own unique URL.

I would also implement a `getUrl()` method on the fragment class to get the URL that the fragment was created with.

So for `getItemPosition()`, I would call `getUrl()` on the fragment passed in, and search my adapter's list for that URL.  Then I would return the index of the URL in the list, or `POSITION_NONE` if it's not there any more.

Then in `getItem()`, I would instantiate a new fragment using the URL at the list position that was passed in.  My rule is that I never instantiate a fragment until the `ViewPager` specifically requests it by calling `getItem()`.

This way, only the `ViewPager` is accessing the fragments, and I don't run into these types of issues.

Also, don't make any changes to the adapter model between the time when `ViewPager` calls `startUpdate()` to when it calls `finishUpdate()`.  This is how `ViewPager` tells your adapter that it's in a "critical section" of figuring out where all the page fragments go.

`PagerAdapter`s can be a bear to work with.  Put some debug logging in your `getCount()`, `getItemPosition()`, and `getItem()` methods so that you can get a feel for how `ViewPager` uses your adapter to manage its pages.

Comment: Here, after calling `getItemPosition` for **fragment0** and **fragment1**, it'll call `instantiateItem` with **position = 1** (page 2) because this is where viewpager learns it needs to insert. If you inspect inside `instantiateItem` of `FragmentPagerAdapter`, you'll see that it'll ultimately return the initial old fragment1 (containerId and ItemId remain same). So in the end, page0 and page2 will show fragment0 and fragment1 and page1 will be blank. I was trying to do the same thing, and this is what happens for me. Please clarify how your code works without overriding `getItemId`.

Comment: It would probably be best if I looked at your code, otherwise we'll go in circles here.  Post a question with your code and reply to this comment with the question link, and I will try to help you out.